How to format a SQL update query for many columns in python?
I'm trying to update a table in MySQL 8.0.35, but it seems like it doesn't like the way I'm formatting this query. I can insert into tables this way, but I get an error when I try to use it to update
import mysql.connector


item_id = 123
query = (f"UPDATE MyTable "
         f"SET (col1, col2, col3, col4) "
         f"VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) "
         f"WHERE item_id = {item_id}")
items = (val1, val2, val3, val4)
cursor.execute(query, items)

But I keep getting this error:
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(col1, col2, col3, col4' at line 1


What I think is wrong in your query is that the UPDATE statement does not accept multiple columns. You might have to do following in order to update values.
import mysql.connector

item_id = 123
query = (f"UPDATE MyTable "
     f"SET col1 = %s, col2 = %s, col3 = %s, col4 = %s "
     f"WHERE item_id = {item_id}")
items = (val1, val2, val3, val4)
cursor.execute(query, items)

By setting val1, val2, val3 and val4 separately, you will be able to run your query without any problem.

the issue here is that the UPDATE statement in MySQL does not support the same syntax like INSERT statement with column lists and VALUES. Here I would suggest to specify the columns to be updated and their corresponding values directly in the SET clause

SET lists each column to update and assigns it a value
%s as placeholders for the values

here is the query
import mysql.connector

item_id = 123
val1 = 'value1'
val2 = 'value2'
val3 = 'value3'
val4 = 'value4'


query = (f"UPDATE MyTable "
         f"SET col1 = %s, col2 = %s, col3 = %s, col4 = %s "
         f"WHERE item_id = %s")


items = (val1, val2, val3, val4, item_id)

cursor.execute(query, items)


The error is due to the UPDATE statement. When updating values in MySQL, you cannot use the VALUES keyword like you would in an INSERT statement. Instead, you need to assign new values directly to the columns.
Use this:
import mysql.connector

item_id = 123
query = (
    "UPDATE MyTable "
    "SET col1 = %s, col2 = %s, col3 = %s, col4 = %s "
    "WHERE item_id = %s"
)
items = (val1, val2, val3, val4, item_id)

cursor.execute(query, items)

